# MongoDB 5.0.3 - mongoexport: BSON field 'saslContinue.mechanism' is an unknown field

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB Latest Version **5.0.3.** When I am trying to export the data using mongoexport command the following error message has come.

```
server returned error on SASL authentication step: BSON field 'saslContinue.mechanism' is an unknown field.
```

Please help me if I am missing anything in the configuration.

Thanks...

Comment: Check the version of mongoexport

Answer (score 0):

I get this error on version 5.0.6.
You can trying to use the lowwer version like 4.4.6 if you don't have to use the latest version.